# Ideas that every salesforce developer should vote for?

Tags: ideas

I've noticed that Ideas around improvements to the apex language don't seem to get the same up-vote exposure as some of the admin-based improvements.

Thinking this might be a good place to aggregate all the ideas that we should be all voting on (for the sake of modernizing development on the platform).

**Here are some of my top:**

[Proper Namespacing](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bp88AAC)

[Proper Class Reflection](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrVa)

[Lambda Expressions](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dk5sAAC)

[Support Field-sets in SOQL SELECT clause](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E3lyQAC) (disclaimer, I submitted this one)

[JSON Serialization Attributes](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxfRAAQ)

### What other ideas should we all be voting for?

Comment: This question not really about the Stack Exchange, but now it's in the `Close Vote` queue for being `Primarily Opinion Based`. I kind of agree that it's not really on topic for the main forum. Can we migrate it back?

Comment: I also thought it fit better in the meta... there are tons of questions in there that are not directly related to this form in particular...

Comment: Moved back to meta http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2361/ideas-that-every-salesforce-developer-should-vote-for

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Good Dev Ideas Community Wiki (no judgement, a-z, if you think it's worthwhile just add it, don't remove ideas added by others).

Vote for everything you agree with to build visibility. If you have opinions on them or disagree with them, comment/downvote on the idea exchange.

- [Ability to update Metadata from Apex (Apex Metadata API)](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l4TkAAI)
- [Add "Switch" or "Case" Statement to Apex](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrSIAA0)
- [Add Apex API for Custom Labels](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000714WAAQ)
- [Allow debug log filtering for test methods](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000iKMpAAM)
- [Allow Record Name to be formula field while allowing autonumber](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brs9AAC)
- [Allow SOQL GROUP BY on formula fields](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HlNtAAK)
- [Apex Code: Implement Iterable on Set.](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxLyAAI)
- [Apex Enum parse from string](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000LfWhAAK)
- [Apex String.format() should take Object[] instead of String[] for arguments](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KlHoAAK)
- [atExit" support for Apex Code](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l5BWAAY)
- [Create an exception class that throws warnings for governor limits](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l5CAAAY)
- [Expand Apex System Assertion methods to handle nulls and type checking.](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LmlkQAC)
- [Get RecordTypeInfos by API name method](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000K9zoAAC)
- [Insufficient Privileges - Tell me why](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bre1AAC)
- [JSON Serialization Annotations](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxfRAAQ)
- [Lambda Expressions](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dk5sAAC)
- [Make Database.upsert Throw Errors at Run-Time Instead of Compile-Time](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000E1eZAAS)
- [Null Coalesce Operator](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cGGlAAM)
- [Private class variables should not be included by Json.Serialize](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kqgQAAQ)
- [Proper Class Reflection](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrVa)
- [Proper Namespacing](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bp88AAC)
- [Provide an additional addError method on SObject that accepts a field name](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000GoC5AAK)
- [Remember static variables set during testSetup annotated methods](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dj51AAC)
- [SANDBOX - REFRESH ABILITY BETWEEN SANDBOXES](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000JawvAAC)
- [SObject model extension classes](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IbMqAAK)
- [Support Field-sets in SOQL SELECT clause](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E3lyQAC)

Comment: I actually disagree with `Private class variables should not be included by Json.Serialize`.  This should be controllable through Attributes though (@JSONIgnore)

Comment: [Remember static variables set during testSetup annotated methods](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dj51AAC) maybe? If people like it, add it to the list.

Comment: we're developers, there is 0% chance we're all going to agree on this list, so if you think your idea is controversial, add it anyway. please be sure to channel any opinions into the idea exchange so the salesforce pms can see.

Answer (score 12):

Split from the community post as this answer as it isn't really developer related.

What is your first thought when you see the [proposed Spring `17 Release logo](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001oku&fId=0D53A00002rsnlx)?

[image: Proposed Spring `17 Release logo]

If something in your head starts going Roy G Biv, then this is the idea for you:

[Correct the color ordering in the Spring `17 Release logo](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cMWlQAM)

Comment: voted for it and going to spread it to my community groups in London

Comment: does marketing not hold anything sacred? i mean it's physics guys

Comment: You canna change the laws of physics. Voted.

Answer (score 8):

My absolute #1 gripe as a developer is shared w/ admins:  "allow triggers *(+WF+PB)* on objects they're not currently allowed on."

Unfortunately, I think the ideas have been fragmented object-by-object in "Ideas."

- Personally, only the lack thereof on OpportunityContactRole ([idea link 1](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrdvAAC), [idea link 2](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DpQGAA0)) impacts me.

But at Dreamforce this year, I learned that there are between 10 & 20 such objects still languishing.  Not sure if there's a master "fix all of them" Idea yet, but I'd vote for that if there were.

It's **really hard to design proper data models** when there are certain tables (especially "junction tables") you can't fire triggers against.

*(Firing triggers around tables they link to is not the same, as close as some clever kludges may get.)*

Answer (score 5):

Definitely had the same feeling (there is even an [idea for a separate dev idea exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000knBTAAY), fortunately since the dev stuff has dedicated PM(s) stuff gets picked up with a lot fewer votes than admin stuff.

That said, more visibility never hurts, and I've got a lot close to my heart, created a wiki response for people to collaborate on a group list instead of having 20 different answers.

Comment: Maybe if dev ideas had a lower threshold, or perhaps we had a better channel for communication?